# How are files distributed in DFS folder targets?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs

I have a Windows DFS made up by 2 servers (Windows Server 2012 R2). Each server have a share folder that was used as target folder for the DFS share. When I create files in the DFS share, I notice the new files are always created on the first server.

Is there any way to configure the file distribution so that files are evenly save on those 2 servers? Thanks!

Comment: The files are going to be replicated between both servers so why does it matter where they're initially created?

Comment: @joeqwerty, I'm not trying to replicate them, but try to find a way to scale out my storage space.

Comment: @Archer, that is not how DFS works.  It does replication (DFS-R) or namespace abstraction (DFS-N).  It does not magically distribute files between multiple servers, for a single share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please double check DFS-R configuration. I think you have not configured a replication of shares between nodes. Check the video starting from 17 min: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AazvgSQwmHk

JFYI, to get a DFS file can be locked once it was opened and released using PeerLock software.
http://www.peersoftware.com/products/dfsr-file-locking/peerlock.html

To get file-shares synchronously replicated between and available from two hosts at the same time you might also consider trying HP VSA http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/data-storage/free-vsa.html or StarWind Virtual SAN Free https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free instead of DFS. You can deploy native SoFS role/File-Share over CSV running on top of shared HA storage which is much more reliable than DFS.